# node js rest api creation not connecting to sql server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

When trying to create a rest api using node js to connect to my database. Following is my code.
The database connection is not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkVqV.jpg)

My Dbconfig file

```
const config = {
    user:'DESKTOP-HLJJ615\RIDERZONE',
    password:'',
    server:'DESKTOP-HLJJ615\SQLEXPRESS',
    database:'Movie',
    options:{
        trustedconnection: true,
        enableArithAort: true,
        instancename: 'SQLEXPRESS'
    },
    port: 49675
}
module.exports = config;
```

my api.js file

```
    var Filmnode = require('./Film8node');
const dboperations = require('./dboperations');
dboperations.getFilm().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

My dboperations.js file

```
var config = require('./dbconfig');
const sql = require('mssql');

async function getFilm(){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let films = await pool.request().query("SELECT * from Film8node");        
        return films.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
module.exports ={
    getFilm : getFilm
}
```

My filmnode.js file

```
class Filmnode{
    constructor(Film_id,film_name,actor,actress,pub_date,director,producer,prod_cost,dist_cost,category,cert_category,poster){
        this.Film_id=Film_id;
        this.film_name=film_name;
        this.actor=actor;
        this.actress=actress;
        this.pub_date=pub_date;
        this.director=director;
        this.producer=producer;
        this.prod_cost=prod_cost;
        this.dist_cost=dist_cost;
        this.category=category;
        this.cert_category=cert_category;
        this.poster=poster;
    }
}

module.exports = Filmnode;
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "filmnodejsapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon api.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.19.0",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "mssql": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When i do npm start the error shows up and not getting connected to the database. dont know what is the issue

Comment: I don't think you are passing the right server value in the config object. If its local development then set it as localhost or pass the IP/Hostname of the server

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @SibiKandathil, its local development. I actually have only windows authentication for my sql server express. Is that a problem? I named it with my ip address also but still getting not connected. username and passwrd were left blank too

Comment: You are supplying `config.user` and `config.password` when trying to connect to a Windows Authenticated instance. Have you tried removing those and replacing with `config.options.trustedConnection: true`?

Comment: instead of windows authentication i now opted sql server authentication. now its working. also added dependency for "msnodesqlv8":"^2.2.0"